# Multiple website server side Clients.All.receiveNotification challenge with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

So I have two websites that I am using SignalR and I have the following in both my Global.asax files:

```
HubConfiguration hubConfig = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfig.EnableCrossDomain = true;
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(hubConfig);
```

I have a server side event side and I get the hub context to send a message to all listening clients:

```
 var signalrContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Notifications.OfferHub>();
signalrContext.Clients.All.receiveNotification("hello world");
```

The same event happens server side on both websites and I would like to broadcast this cross-domain to all listening clients. I am thinking this is not possible server side because I will not be able to get the HubContext for both websites change the hub.url server side.

Unless anyone has any other suggestions?

Comment: Just because the class exists in both projects doesn't mean your clients are connected to the right application. See this sample https://github.com/SignalR/Samples/tree/master/BasicChat.CrossDomain

Comment: Thanks dfowler based on the examples you shared with me, my situation would be not difficult to solve if I were making client calls and could set a hub's url to a remote server. One way to do this would be to detect which website was the client caller and set the url to the other website.

But I have server side events and server side data that I want to transmit on all cross-domain listening clients...

Comment: What you have is not cross domain at all. I'm not sure what you're expecting. You can't expect the hub to broadcast to clients on another server just because you have a dll reference. There needs to be an active connection to the server...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it took me a minute to realize what do here. Thanks to David Fowler for his help and SignalR awesomeness! I ended up adding a ServiceReference in each website to a web service in the other website and calling a "Broadcast" WebMethod. The web service webmethod just gets the current SignalR context and broadcasts my message to all clients listening on the respective website.